# cannot remove docker container and the all of the images had deleted

Tags: docker

I had remove all images and remove container but still have one cannot removed,the error message is :

```
Error response from daemon: container ac19d83b3b596bf8a995ce99500b12a0881ae4e1af067aaa2063dfcceb5a4314: 

driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem:

remove/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a64ec712b637a9c245a4213e3b97aaeacd3c04d7218b4b7902ec3a5e75bb33fb/diff/home/wwwroot/default/.user.ini: operation not permitted
```

my docker info :

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-30-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.689GiB
Name: Blank
ID: CG5D:XHVM:6QCM:ENF5:GDJ5:GHSD:6VU4:UOPM:2RCC:QMH5:WKNM:IZTZ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

How can I fix

Answer (score 0):

Even trying to remove it with the -f option isn't working for you?
This should remove all containers:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```